Two manifolds are unoriented cobordant if and only if they have the same Stiefel–Whitney numbers
Could anyone explain this fact to me and/or refer me to a source with an adequate explanation?
Assume that we know the dimension of each cobordism group $\mathfrak{N}_n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2.$
Or assume that we even know the full structure of the cobordism ring $\mathfrak{N}_{*},$ that is, we know that it is the polynomial algebra over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with a single generator in each dimension that is not in the form $2^k-1$.
I thought that the fact in the title of the question is supposed to be an easy corollary, but Stong in "Notes on Cobordism Theory" explains only the direction "cobordant $\implies$ the characteristic numbers are the same" and does that in a very hand-wavy manner. I even tried looking it up in Thom's original paper, but there he only states it, calling it a corollary.
I am weak at topology, but it seems like it should not be too difficult to understand. Also, I am very surprised that I did not manage to find it written out anywhere.
Thank you very much!

Milnor and Stasheff, "Characteristic Classes," Princeton University Press. Section 4 gives details of the thing you describe as "hand wavy" but then notes that "The converse theorem, due to Thom, is much harder to prove  [theorem statement omitted] For proof, the reader is referred to [Stong]."
So at least that gives details of one part.

A more modern proof of the hard direction can be found in Peter May's A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology, Chapter 25.

idk, it seems that Milnor and Stasheff cannot use the theorem on the structure of $\mathfrak{N}_{*}$ (because it is not in the book), so they must prove it only using knowledge of characteristic classes, hence it is more difficult. For May, the proof is much harder than I expected. I really hoped for something simple that takes advantage of the results on cobordisms. Anyway, thank you both!
